# Get last data for rows

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

[image: table main]

then i want query data like this :

[image]

how did to do that?

Comment: Please add a description of your expactation

Comment: description of what? i've already asking how to do query like table 2

Comment: Yes but what is the logic behind that?

Comment: oh, i need the value of last Attempt each Serial_Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery with `group by` should do the job:

```
select * from <table_name> 
where (serial_number, attempt) in (select serial_number, max(attempt) from <table_name> group by serial_number)
```